# comare 2 array and get id flutter

Tags: flutter

I have 2 array and i need to get id by comparing both array

Here is my first array

```
[
  {
    "optid": "20",
    "ids": [
      {
        "id": "16",
        "desc": "test 1"
      },
      {
        "id": "12",
        "optionCode": "test 2"
      },
      {
        "id": "6",
        "optionCode": "test 3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "optid": "22",
    "ids": [
      {
        "id": "20",
        "desc": "test 1"
      },
      {
        "id": "15",
        "optionCode": "test 2"
      },
      {
        "id": "6",
        "optionCode": "test 3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "optid": "23",
    "ids": [
      {
        "id": "17",
        "desc": "test 1"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "optionCode": "test 2"
      },
      {
        "id": "6",
        "optionCode": "test 3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is my second array

```
[
  {
    "id": 17,
    "name": "test 1"


  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "test 2"


  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "tes t3"
   

  }
]
```

I need output **optid - 23** as output , so how it can be done , looping is one option but is there any other option available

How to get the value by comparing 2 array with respect to id and get the desired output

Comment: Do you need to retrieve items only based on the content of the second array?

Comment: yes..........................

Comment: Is this structure a class or a string?

Comment: json array........

Answer (score 0):

If you are retrieving data from JSON, solution be like this:

```dart
class Data {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  Data(this.id, this.name);

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Data(json['id'], json['name']);
  }
}

final json = jsonDecode(yourData);
final dataList = json.map(Data.fromJson).toList();
```

The same is valid for parsing data from your list, where content inside - `Map<String, dynamic`.